# gtk - After calling external command, how to prevent it from closing gtk main window

Tags: gtk, phpexcel

I want to read data from GtkListStore and build an excel by phpExcel. First, I build a php file according to the GtkListStore, then I use php and phpexcel lib to compile and build execl file.

In my gtk code (compile in MinGW environment), I use `execvp(cmd[0], (const char **)cmd);` to call the external command -- php. In fact, `cmd[0]` is php.exe and cmd[1], cmd[2] ... are the parameters for php. After calling the php command, my gtk main window is closed and it quits my gtk program.

How can I prevent the php command from quitting main program? Should I use something else instead of `execvp`? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`execvp()` and friends replace the current process with another process, so it's no surprise that your program quits. Use [`g_spawn_sync()`](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.32/glib-Spawning-Processes.html#g-spawn-sync) or a related function - that will run your php program, then return control to your original program.

Comment: Thank ptomato. I think `g_spawn_sync` is what I want. But it didn't work. My program is running in `MinGW`. Using `if(!g_spawn_sync(NULL, argv, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &out, &stder, &exit, &error))` will output error message `Failed to execute helper program (No such file or directory)`. The `argv` is `char *argv[] = { "ls", NULL }` -- a simple `ls` command. What's wrong about it?

Comment: Make sure to use `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH` in the flags, otherwise the `ls` command will not be found, since it is not in your current directory.

Comment: I just tried the code mentioned above in a pure Linux environment at home. It still didn't work. But, if I use absolute path, e.g., "/bin/ls", it worked. However, when I was in office and run the program in a `MinGW` environment, I tried absolute path and relative path, none worked. So, I am a little confused now. Is the question about the `MinGW` environment? One more thing, I use gtk2.10.11(a very old version) in MinGW and use gtk2.24.6 at home. Is it a version problem?

Comment: In MinGW, I used absolute path, e.g., argv[0] = "c:\\php\\php.exe" and argv[1] = "c:\\user\\foo.php", as I don't have to use the flag `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH`, but it failed and said "No such file".

Comment: Forward slash didn't work. In a pure Linux environment, both absolute path and relative path work. In MinGW, none of them works. Really strange. I couldn't find way in MinGW:(. Is it possible that `g_spawn_sync` of version gtk2.10.11 for MinGW has bug?

Comment: After reading source code of "gspawn-win32.c", `Failed to execute helper program` means `Check if gspawn-win32-helper couldn't be run`. I found `gspawn-win32-helper.exe` doesn't exist in my gtk2.10.11 directory. Then I changed to gtk2.22.1 in my computer which includes gspawn-win32-helper.exe. After recompiling, it still didn't work. Is it a clue I mean what's the function of gspawn-win32-helper.exe.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean gtk2.10 doesn't use helper program? For gtk2.10 arc code, I just googled it but I didn't find it. Maybe it is too old. On the other hand, what does the helper program mean? Does it result in command couldn't be found?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16301/discussion-between-warem-and-ptomato)

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer my own question. Followed is the summary to what I have googled and tried within the past few days. It has nothing new but maybe is useful to a newbie like me.

First, thank ptomato. To avoid my problem in GTK, it must use `g_spawn_sync` or related functions. If your command is absolute path, you don't have to use the flag `G_SPAWN_SEARCH_PATH`, otherwise, make sure to use the flag.

Following are something related in `MinGW` environment.

-> gspawn-win32-helper.exe
In MinGW, to use g_spawn_sync, it must have `gspawn-win32-helper.exe` installed. When I installed GTK environment, I only extracted the useful lib or exe file I think it is useful then I missed gspawn-win32-helper.exe and it resulted in the problem -- `Failed to execute helper program (No such file or directory)` mentioned in the above comments. After extracting gspawn-win32-helper.exe from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/glib/2.10/win32/glib-2.10.0.zip and installing it, g_spawn_sync worked.

-> For canonical Windows paths, both double backslashes and single forward slash work, e.g., c:/foo/bar and c:\foo\bar work.